# avrdude: Error: butterfly programmer uses avr_write_page() but does not provide a cmd() method

Tags: uploading, avrdude, linux, upload

When trying to flash my sketch, I see many errors such as:

```
 ***failed;                                                                                                                            
 ***failed;                                                                                                                            
 ***failed;                                                                                                                            
avrdude: Error: butterfly programmer uses avr_write_page() but does not                                                                
provide a cmd() method.                                                                                                                                                                                           
 *** page 127 (addresses 0x7400 - 0x747f) failed to write
```

And also:

```
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: set addr
```

How can I successfully flash my sketch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After much frustration in trying things, I came across [this forum post](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=129647.msg3039571#msg3039571) which advised:

```
sudo systemctl stop ModemManager.service
```

If this works, disable the service from starting next boot:

```
sudo systemctl disable ModemManager.service
```

It seems like setting `ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"` in a `udev` rule is insufficient.